# Coroutine suspend function and blocking calls

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

Below is my use case.
 I have a function `fun requestFocus` this function in turn call function `fun configure` which depends on a callback from system hence this function **configure** uses coundownlatch with count 1 and await until it is reset to zero when callback is received. 
 For this I have marked `requestFocus` suspend and use Dispatchers.IO to do all its operation.
 Now there are multiple caller of **requestFocus**  for ex function `fun accept`. The function **accept** does many things and all of them happens on same thread. function **accept** can also be called from main thread or intent service as well. My problem is since function configure is blocking I do not want to block main thread. 
 Currently accept function looks like this

```
fun accept() {
    //do something
    requestFocus()
    // do something
}
```

I am not sure how I can call requestFocus from accept and have all the operation that happens post requestFocus execution to happen in same way. What I have done currently in accept function is below

```
fun accept() {
    //do something
    runBlocking{
    requestFocus()
    // do something
}
```

But this creates problem as main thread gets blocked. Any suggestion what can I try? I have looked into documentation of Global scope and main scope.

Comment: Never use `runBlocking` except in a unit test. It otherwise completely defeats the purpose of coroutines. Use `lifecycleScope.launch` to start a coroutine. This is sort of like posting a Runnable to the main thread, but the code within the lambda can suspend and therefore call `suspend` functions. So if `accept()` represents a complete flow of logic, use `fun accept() = lifecycleScope.launch { /*...*/ }`.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for `withContext` block. `withContext` behaves similar to `runBlocking` but it suspends the thread instead of blocking it.

```
suspend fun accept() {
    //do something on calling thread
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO){ // Changes to Dispatchers.IO and suspends the calling thread
        requestFocus() // Calls requestFocus() on Dispatchers.IO
        // do something on Dispatchers.IO
    }
    // Resumes calling thread
}
```

You need to call `accept` from a coroutine scope or from another suspending function. Or you can create a coroutine with `launch` to start a coroutine:

```
fun accept() = launch(Dispatchers.Main) { // Starts a coroutine on the main thread
    //do something on main thread
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO){ // Changes to Dispatchers.IO and suspends the main thread
        requestFocus() // Calls requestFocus() on Dispatchers.IO
        // do something on Dispatchers.IO
    }
    // Resumes main thread
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It made things bit more clear to me. However as I said accept can be called from main and as well as background thread. So is it possible to do launch(inside accept) on the thread accept was called? Like by your second solution it will always be main thread. So just curious if its possible in coroutine

Comment: It is possible but if you want a sequencial-like execution then using `launch` won't work. When you create a coroutine with `launch`, you're creating a subprocess and the thread that creates that coroutine won't be suspended, so it will continue its execution so `accept` might finish before the coroutine you created inside it finishes. My second solution creates a coroutine and starts running on the main thread but if you remove `Dispatchers.Main` it will create a coroutine and start running on whatever thread you call `accept`.

Comment: Thanks. Just one more thing,  Like I said I am using coundownlatch and await inside configure method which is called by requestFocus. I want to know if its good approach as countdown will hold the thread and block it. Is there any better alternative in kotlin-coroutine. For ex I know coroutine has delay instead of thread.sleep to work with coroutine, does it have similar thing for countdown use case?

Comment: You could replicate Countdownlatch behavior with coroutines. For example, create a lazy coroutine like this `val job = launch(start = CoroutineStart.LAZY) {...}` and start it with `job.start()` whenever you need. To verify that a coroutine is running you can do it like this `if(job.isActive) {...}` and wait for a coroutine to finish with `job.join()`.